# How do I implement overflow-hidden in react-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I hope my <Form.Control/> won't be effect when user scroll up or down, because if the input value is a number, scroll up/down will effect the value, I want to avoid it

this is so far I've tried

```
    <Form.Control
                    type="number"
                    className = "overflow-hidden" 
    <Form.Control/>
```

Comment: you forgot to close the first part `<Form.Control type="number" className = "overflow-hidden">  <Form.Control/>` or simply `<Form.Control type="number" className = "overflow-hidden" />`

Perhaps you need to use `variant` instead of `className`

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/theming/

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the scroll up and down buttons by adding this CSS style

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work... how can I implement it for my CSS? also it's not a button